# Can we improve fragment move in/out animation priority?

Tags: android, animation, fragment, render

I have a fragment A and a fragment B, when I press a button on A,  B will replace A, B will have a animation when move from right to left, the animatiion will last about 300ms.
In fragment B, it will request a http net content (some url of images), then display the images with a gridview.

The problem is when B get the content, the animation is still moving, the render of B will last for a whole and stop the animation, so it looks like the move animation was stopped for a while.

Is there any way we can guarantee that the render of B  after the animation, so the animation will looks more smooth?

Comment: can u show code , where r u rendering image in fragment B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider loading B's content on a different thread ([background/worker thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), etc.) to free up the UI thread for rendering your animation. Based on the info you've given, I'd recommend using an asynchronous task to load your images. As DIVA suggested, if you post some of your code it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for all your's suggestion, I will have a try and feed back then.

Comment: The fragment B has a viewPage contains 3 tabs, and it cached all the page data, I reduced the cached pages and the animatiion looks better.